# QUERY_STRING with parameter

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting, query-string, url-parameters

Suppose I have URL with query string parameter like these:

```
/index.php?test=MYID
```

Using mod_rewrite, how can I redirect them to SES URL like these?

```
/index.php?view=MYID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^test=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?view=%1 [L,R=301]
```